# Manter documentação do Swagger atualizada

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Estou documentando uma API com Swagger. Não estou utilizando anotações e a documentação é gravada em um arquivo JSON.

O problema é que API está em constante mudança e a cada alteração é preciso comparar o arquivo com o código-fonte Java.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de automatizar essa tarefa ou se vocês teriam alguma dica.

Comment: Em algum momento a API vai parar de ser modificada, certo? Eu acho que até esse momento não tem muito o que fazer... O jeito é ir atualizando manualmente até que a API chegue numa versão "estável"